# Will movement of charged gaseous particles constitute electrical current?

Tags: electricity

As electrons flow, they constitute current.

So if we manage to supply an extra electron to each of the gaseous molecules present in an enclosure and make the gaseous molecules travel in that enclosure, will that constitute current?

Is this kind of a thing feasible?

Answer (score 5):

Any spatial movement of charge constitutes an electrical current. Thus also the movement of gas ions, whether positively or negatively charged, produces an electrical current. Currents produced by ionized gas molecules are very common. For example in gas discharge tubes used for illumination.